# Contour integrals on unit circle.

Tags: contour-integration

When dealing with a contour along a unit circle, we can set $|z| = 1$ and $z(t) = e^{it}$ so that $\frac{d z}{dt} = ie^{it}$ with $t\in [0,2\pi]$.

Find the integral of:

$$\int_{\Gamma}(z^7+z^4) dz$$

My own attempt.

$$\int_{\Gamma} (z^7+z^5)dz = \int_0^{2\pi}((e^{it})^7+(e^{it})^5)(ie^{it})dt $$
$$i\int_0^{2\pi}e^{8it}+e^{6it}dt$$

Am I doing it right? It doesn't seem like the right answer but I can't find anything that says it's not. How would it be done using the Residue Theorem?

Comment: Have you studied Cauchy's Theorem? You are also applying the definition of contour integral wrongly.

Comment: Two comments.  First, an integral expression $\int\cdots dz$ has implied brackets, $\int(\cdots)\,dz$.  In your first step it looks like you are thinking of the integral as $\int z^7+(z^5\,dz)$, but it should be $\int(z^7+z^5)dz$.  Second, you may need to revise power laws: $(e^{it})^5(ie^{it})=e^{5it}\,ie^{it}=ie^{6it}$.

Comment: David - Thanks for pointing it out and i agree completely.  

greeth290krm - I have, and i can see that now. Thanks.

Comment: To use residue theorem, you just need to see that there are no residues as polynomials are holomorphic functions . Hence the integral is $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not correct. It should be\begin{align}\int_\Gamma z^7+z^5\,\mathrm dz&=\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\left(e^{it}\right)^7+\left(e^{it}\right)^5\right)ie^{it}\,\mathrm dt\\&=i\int_0^{2\pi}e^{8it}+e^{6it}\,\mathrm dt\\&=i\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(8t)+i\sin(8t)+\cos(6t)+i\sin(6t)\,\mathrm dt\\&=i\left[\frac{\sin(8t)}8+i\frac{-\cos(8t)}8+\frac{\sin(6t)}6+i\frac{-\cos(6t)}6\right]_{t=0}^{t=2\pi}\\&=0.\end{align}

Comment: Antidifferentiating $e^{8it}$ to get $e^{9it}/9i$ implicitly relies on the exponential function being holomorphic.  Not saying you are wrong of course, but in case the OP has not yet studied complex antidifferentiation, it might be safer to integrate real and imaginary parts separately.

Comment: David is correct in amusing i haven't studied Antidifferentiation yet.

Comment: @David I've edited my answer.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you, it makes perfect sense now!

Comment: @ChrisCrossAppleSause I'm glad I could help.